# Sandbox - Notification of Payment Received but facilitator account not topped

Tags: paypal

I've just started to get the Paypal link to integrate with my website and it says the payment went through (i.e. the money is deducted from the buyer sandbox account) however, the facilitator of the account does not have its money increased.

Does anyone else have this problem?